# Git diff not working on Github Actions -fatal: bad object 7100c3bbc34a9667ca9034a8ec321677ed4b5828

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-diff

I want to see the diff between a file between two commits on Github Actions. Here is my `main.yml` file:

```
name: GitHub Actions Test
on: [push]
jobs:
  Test-GitHub-Actions:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Adding actions/checkout@v2
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Git diff
        run: git diff 7100c3bbc34a9667ca9034a8ec321677ed4b5828 4c5952b60b8a5911154534ea1fefec3567c49c52 ${{ github.workspace }}/data.xml
      - name: Run Python
        run: |
          python3 ${{ github.workspace }}/.github/workflows/app.py
      - name: Setup git - step 1
        run: git config --global user.email "adithraghavs@gmail.com"
      - name: Setup git - step 2
        run: git config --global user.name "Adith Raghav"
      - name: Check for changes
        run: git status
      - name: Stage changed files
        run: git add .
      - name: Commit changed files
        run: git commit -m "auto updating history.json and maybe checked for changes in data"
      - name: fetch from main 
        run: git fetch origin main
      - name: Push to main
        run: git push origin HEAD:main
```

I get the following error on Github Actions:

```
fatal: bad object 7100c3bbc34a9667ca9034a8ec321677ed4b5828
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

I do not know what this is supposed to mean. It works perfectly on my local. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe your local repository has the object 64252781112f8d3c890d930c2c074fbc6509da96 but the repository on GitHub does not.

Comment: At which step does this error occur exactly?

Comment: At the step called "Git diff"

Comment: @mkrieger1, I'm not sure I understand. Both are in the same repo.

Comment: Are you sure the error is not "fatal: bad object 7100c3bbc34a9667ca9034a8ec321677ed4b5828"?

Comment: Your local repo and the repo on GitHub may be conceptually "the same" but technically they are two different repositories. You need to synchronize them with push/fetch commands.

Comment: @mkrieger1 this is the error, I confused it with an earlier test with different hashes: fatal: bad object 7100c3bbc34a9667ca9034a8ec321677ed4b5828

Comment: @mkrieger1 That I've done. Both are already up to date.

Comment: Try changing order of the sha in git diff. Instead of `git diff sha1 sha2` use `git diff sha2 sha1`

Answer (score 5):

Set `fetch-depth` to `0` in checkout action.

```
- name: Adding actions/checkout@v2
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
```

[See here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25797#discussioncomment-3249294) for details.

Answer (score -3):

Never<sup>1</sup> use a raw hash ID in a GitHub Action.

Be aware that `checkout@v2` makes a *shallow clone*.  A shallow clone is one that omits various Git objects on purpose so as to clone faster.  Such a clone cannot be used for most *Git* purposes; it's mainly good for *compiling code* (e.g., in a Jenkins or other builder).  Probably, this particular action would have worked for one-time usage had you used the v1 checkout, or set the depth.

While this is sort of a Git issue, it's mainly a problem in that you've written a useless GitHub Action.  See GitHub's articles on writing proper GitHub Actions to figure out how to write one that doesn't break like this.  There's not really much else to be said here, other than "don't use raw hash IDs" and "know about shallow clones" and the "depth" parameter for the `checkout@v2` action.

---

<sup>1</sup>Insert [G&S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_and_Sullivan) [HMS-Pinafore](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/W._S._Gilbert#H.M.S._Pinafore_(1878)) routine as usual.

Comment: The Action isn't useless; this reproduces the same error as the one I'm using for my code.

Comment: What can I use instead of a raw hash ID?

Comment: Generally, instead of a raw hash ID you'd have a name: a branch name like `refs/heads/somebranch`, a tag name like `refs/tags/v1.2`, a remote-tracking name, or some other name. In some cases, you'll *start* with a name and then manipulate it to find a merge base or other related hash ID. So you'd get a full (or sufficiently deep) clone and use `git merge-base incoming base` (add `refs/heads/` as needed). For `git diff`, note that the *three*-dot syntax `id-A...id-B` will automatically find the (or a) merge base between the two IDs (given as names or hash IDs) and diff that against the second.

Comment: @mkrieger1: [Gilbert & Sullivan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.M.S._Pinafore). There's a famous song in it (["I am the captain of the Pinafore ..."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBK39BKWuQg)) that has a whole "what never? no never!" bit in it.