# Retrieve commit message in a GH Action triggered on pull request

Tags: git, github-actions, pull-request, git-commit, github-webhook

I want to create a GitHub Actions workflow triggered on pull_request. The workflow should get the last commit message in the Pull Request and check it against a given regular expression.

The part I am struggling on is actually getting the last commit message.

My workflow looks like this:

```yaml
---
name: CI-PR-Check

on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
 
      - name: Check commit message
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "commit message validation"
          message=$(git log --pretty=%B -n 1)
          python ${{ github.action_path }}/commitcheck.py "$message"
```

I expected the line `message=$(git log --pretty=%B -n 1)` to get me the message of the last commit, but I get the message from the pull request, so something like `Merge <some sha> into <other sha>`.

Using [GitHub webhook events](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads?actionType=opened#pull_request), I am able to get the sha of the commit that I am interested in using `sha="${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}"`. However, it is still not possible to get the commit message with `git log --format=%B -n 1 $sha`. I get an error `fatal: bad object <my sha>`.

Is there any way to get my commit message ?

Comment: It sounds like you want the second parent, in which case you can probably just tack on `HEAD^2` to the end of your command.

Comment: Side Note, the premise feels odd to me. Suppose someone is PR'ing a branch with 5 commits. You are assuming the 5th commit will have a specific message that you are interested in?

Comment: `actions/checkout` is _shallow_ by default, so other commits won't be accessible.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that sounds like the first sentence of a good answer to this question. ;)

Comment: [Searching for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-actions%5D+%22fatal%3A+bad+object%22) finds this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71204693/3001761

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Tried [this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/28474) solution, but it doesn't seem to work. Did you find a solution?