List differing Commits in PR does not work in GitHub Action
I am trying to list commits that are differing between the main branch and my current branch in a script that's also being utilized by a GitHub action:
$ git log --pretty="format:%h" --right-only $(git remote show)/main..$(git branch --show-current)
19edbd5
7c7aab7
d67a802

That doesn't work in a GitHub action because the current branch is empty - so is HEAD. I suppose this is due to the detached head mode of PRs. Tried to git switch origin/$GITHUB_HEAD_REF but to no avail.
I could use the gh cli but that script should have as less dependencies as possible. Can you tell me what's wrong with this approach?

What fetch-depth is set in your checkout action? Try setting it to 0

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76769122/7976758

Thanks both of you! That pretty much did the trick

I did vote for duplicate myself - anything else I can do to speed up closing this?
